# Which is more efficient in mysql, a big join or multiple queries of single table?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database like this

Post – 500,000 rows (Postid,Userid)

Photo – 200,000 rows (Photoid,Postid)

About 50,000 posts have photos, average 4 each, most posts do not have photos.

I need to get a feed of all posts with photos for a userid, average 50 posts each.

Which approach would be more efficient?

1: Big Join

```
select * 
    from post 
        left join photo on post.postid=photo.postid 
    where post.userid=123
```

2: Multiple queries

```
select * from post where userid=123

while (loop through rows) {

    select * from photo where postid=row[postid]

}
```

Comment: as this is nondestructive, read-only query: just try it! from a theoretical point of view, as everybody answered below

Answer (score 4):

I've not tested this, but I very much suspect (at an almost cellular level) that **a join would be vastly, vastly faster** - what you're attempting is pretty much the reason why joins exist after all.

Additionally, there would be considerably less overhead in terms of scripting language <-> MySQL communications, etc. but I suspect that's somewhat of a mute factor.

Comment: +1 for "what you're attempting is pretty much the reason why joins exist after all"

Answer (score 1):

The JOIN is always faster with proper indexing (as mentioned before) but several smaller queries may be more easily cached, provided of course that you are using the query cache. The more tables a query contains the greater the chances of more frequent invalidations.

As long as the parsing and optimization procedure, I believe MySQL maintains its own statistics internally and this usually happens once. What you are losing when executing multiple queries is the roundtrip time and the client buffering lag, which is small if the resultset is relatively small in size.

Answer (score 0):

A join will be much faster.

Each separate query will need to be parsed, optimized and executed which takes quite long.

Just don't forget to create the following indexes:

```
post (userid)
photo (postid)
```

Answer (score 0):

With proper indexing on the postid columns, the join should be superior.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the possibility of a sub-query:
`SELECT * FROM photo WHERE postid IN (SELECT postid FROM post WHERE userid = 123);`

I'd start with optimizing your queries, e.g. `select * from post where userid=123` is obviously not needed as you only use `row[postid]` in your loop, so don't `select *` if you want to split the query.
Then I'd run a couple of tests which ones faster but JOINing just two tables is usually the fastest (don't forget to create an index where needed).

If you're planning to make your "big query" very big (by joining more tables), things can get very slow and you may need to split your query. I once joined seven tables which took the query to run 30 seconds. Splitting the query made in run in a fraction of a second.

Comment: A subquery will make `photo` the leading table in the plan, which is not a good thing given the numbers provided by the @op.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that there's another possibility, I recommended the JOIN afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this but there is another option. It might be much slower or faster depending upon indexes used.

In your case, something like:

```
select t1.postid FROM (select postid from post where userid = 23) AS t1 JOIN photo ON t1.postid = photo.postid
```

If the number of rows in table t1 is going to be small compared to table post there might be a chance for considerable performance improvement. But I haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM photo, post 
WHERE post.userid = 123 AND photo.postid = post.postid;
```

If you only want posts with photos, construct your query starting with the photo table as your base table.  Note, you will get the post info repeated with each result row.

If you didn't want to return all of the post info with each row, an alternative would be to

```
SELECT DISTINCT postid from photo, post where post.userid = 123;
```

Then foreach postid, you could

```
SELECT * from photo WHERE postid = $inpostid;
```